# Why numpy is behaving differenly for array slicing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, slice

I was learning numpy when i stumbled across  this wierd thing while slicing arrays.
One creates a reference other value

```
    >>> x = np.ones((3,3))
    >>> x
    array([[ 1., 1., 1.],
          [ 1., 1., 1.],
          [ 1., 1., 1.]])
    #last column is repeated
    >>> y=x[:,[0,1,2,2]]
    >>> y
    array([[ 1., 1., 1., 1.],
         [ 1., 1., 1., 1.],
         [ 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
    >>> x[0,0]=999 # change element in x
    >>> x
    array([[ 999., 1., 1.],
          [ 1., 1., 1.],
          [ 1., 1., 1.]])
    >>> y # its not changed!
    array([[ 1., 1., 1., 1.],
         [ 1., 1., 1., 1.],
         [ 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

But this actually creates a reference

```
>>> x = np.ones((3,3))
>>> y = x[:2,:2] # view of upper left piece
>>> x[0,0] = 999 
>>> x
array([[ 999., 1., 1.], #here value has changed in X
[ 1., 1., 1.],
[ 1., 1., 1.]])
>>> y
array([[ 999., 1.], #  y also changed!
[ 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: i know u can use 
`>>>y = x.copy() #if u want to copy`
but while slicing what if i dont want to copy

Comment: This is worth reading over too: [Views versus copies in NumPy](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html)